# Bypass a single Apache rewrite condition but continue processing all other conditions

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, processwire

Trying to help a friend with getting his ProcessWire site running correctly. There's a line in the htacess like this:

```
# PW-PAGENAME
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# 16A. Ensure that the URL follows the name-format specification required by PW
# See also directive 16b below, you should choose and use either 16a or 16b. 
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/~?[-_.a-zA-Z0-9/]*$"
```

He'd like to exclude a specific directory "/images/" from that single specific condition and then continue on with processing the other conditions.

I've tried so many different things but none of them have worked but it seems like something that should be simple and that I should know how to do :-) but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A RewriteCond doesn't do anything by itself, it just holds a condition that needs to be true in order for the next RewriteRule to be processed. Here's a larger excerpt of the `.htaccess` included in ProcessWire (without comments):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/~?[-_.a-zA-Z0-9/]*$"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?it=$1 [L,QSA]
```

All the RewriteCond directives only limit which requests get rewritten to ProcessWire's `index.php` file. Namely, the following types of requests don't get handled by ProcessWire according to those rules:

- Non-ASCII paths (`[-_.a-zA-Z0-9/]*`), though you can use [directive 16b](https://github.com/processwire/processwire/blob/master/htaccess.txt#L369-L375) to change that.
- Existing files and directories (`!-f`, `!-d`)
- Some specific files (`!(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)`)

How you need to modify this depends on how you want files inside your images folder to be handled.

### Apache serves static files

You probably don't need to change anything if you just want images in your image directory to be handled directly by the server, because files are excluded by the existing RewriteConds already.

That said, if you want don't want **any** paths that begin with `/images/` to be handled by ProcessWire, add another RewriteCond before the RewriteRule, something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?it=$1 [L,QSA]
```

### ProcessWire serves static files

If you want images inside your `images` folder to be served by ProcessWire instead of the server, you would have to modify multiple of the existing RewriteConds. It will probably be easier to duplicate the RewriteRule with a seperate RewriteCond that will only match that specific path. The following directives (added behind the existing RewriteRule) will rewrite all requests that start with `/images/`, allowing those to be handled by ProcessWire.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?it=$1 [L,QSA]
```